# Find missing date and add them into result - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a query that looks like this:

```
  SELECT count(*)
        ,date_format(created, '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated
    FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
GROUP BY DATE(created)
ORDER BY created ASC
```

The problem is that some dates are missing in the database. I need to have those dates into the results showing the date's count as 0 and the date itself. How can I do it please?
Thanks

***EDIT:***

**count(*)** is in the left column
**created** is the right one

a) data:

```
2610, 11/04/17
1332, 12/04/17
2082, 26/04/17
3584, 27/04/17
```

b) expected result:

```
2610   11/04/17 
1332   12/04/17 
0      13/04/17 
0      14/04/17 
0      15/04/17 
0      16/04/17 
0      17/04/17 
0      18/04/17 
0      19/04/17 
0      20/04/17 
0      21/04/17 
0      22/04/17 
0      23/04/17 
0      24/04/17 
0      25/04/17 
2082   26/04/17 
3584   27/04/17
```

c) actual result:

```
2610    11/04/17
1332    12/04/17
2082    26/04/17
3584    27/04/17
```

Comment: If the date is missing, how can we retrieve it?

Comment: If created is `NULL`, what date are you going to represent then in your result?

Comment: The problem is that it's not in the database, it's just missing and I was wondering if it's possible to add the missing dates and number (= 0) within the query

Comment: Create a temp table with all the dates in it, the join back to that temp table from your query. Show NULL as 0.

Comment: GROUP BY and SELECT the same columns, either date_format(created, '%d/%m/%y ') or DATE(created).

Comment: @Leonidas199x I am quite new to mysql, can you show me how to do that please?

Comment: Try `GROUP BY DATE(datecreated)` and see what happens

Comment: @ethrbunny doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to expand your question to include a) data b) expected results c) actual results..

Comment: @ethrbunny done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might not be a perfect solution, but this might give you the result:
the second query after `UNION ALL` in the inner SELECT should return all dates between the `MIN(created)` and the `MAX(created)` of your table with the counter value 0.

```
    SELECT SUM(a.ctr)
      ,a.datecreated
  FROM 
  (

    SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr, date_format(created, '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated 
    FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
UNION ALL 
    select 0 as ctr, date_format(selected_date, '%d/%m/%y ') as datecreated 
       from 
     (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
    where selected_date 
    between (SELECT MIN(created) FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips)
        and (SELECT MAX(created) FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips)
   ) a
   group by a.datecreated
   order by month(a.datecreated), date(a.datecreated)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but only in part. It does add the zero where there is no data the problem is that it adds zero for every date giving me something like this:
`'0','2017-04-11'
'2610','2017-04-11 05:20:06'
'0','2017-04-12'
'1332','2017-04-12 05:20:04'`

Comment: so basically it does what you want to have, just the datatype is not perfect? so you would just have to cast the values?

Comment: @GPecchio i just updated my answer and added the date_format(...) - does it work now?

Comment: it does work now but the results are sorted by day number and not chronologically and I can't figure out how to sort it. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: the last line says "order by a.datecreated" - so the result should be sorted by the datecreated

Comment: @GPecchio if the output is already like you expected (except the order), don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, so other users find the right answer later without reading the whole comments

Comment: Marked it. But it is not sorted correctly. How do I correctly chronologically sort it?

Comment: @GPecchio: could you create a little rextester http://rextester.com/ with test data? like a create statement, inserting some records to the table, to make it easier to reproduce everything? don't forget to save the rextester and post the link

Comment: The problem is that the data come from a database that is the company's and it's pretty complicated to recreate. Any other idea why it might not be sorting please? Thanks

Comment: @GPecchio of course not a lot of data. just do a rextester with the create statement and a few inserts, like 5 or 10 records with testdata, similiar to your production data

Comment: @GPecchio: script is not running. i am not too familiar with mysql to find the error in this case

Comment: Same that's the problem