# Find gaps between timestamp of 1 hour and group by hour, date, week and month - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mysql-workbench

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT count(*), date_format(created, '%H:%i - %d/%m/%y') as 
datecreated
FROM mimesi_realtime.served_clips
where created > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
group by date_format(created, '%H - %d/%m/%y')
order by min(created) ASC;
```

It basically does a count for every hour in the last 48 hours and it sorts the results in a chronological order

The problem is that during the night, in particular between 22:00 and 5:00 no data is registered and I need the count showing 0 for every hour anyway

**count(*)** is in the left column
**created** is the right one

a) actual result:

```
 - 261, 20:00 - 11/04/17
 - 133, 21:00 - 11/04/17
 - 208, 22:00 - 11/04/17 
 - 358, 5:00  - 12/04/17
 - 489, 6:00  - 12/04/17
```

b) expected result:

```
 - 261, 20:00 - 11/04/17
 - 133, 21:00 - 11/04/17
 - 208, 22:00 - 11/04/17
 - 0,   23:00 - 11/04/17
 - 0,   24:00 - 11/04/17
 - 0,   1:00  - 12/04/17
 - 0,   2:00  - 12/04/17
 - 0,   3:00  - 12/04/17
 - 0,   4:00  - 12/04/17
 - 358, 5:00  - 12/04/17
 - 489, 6:00  - 12/04/17
```

Is there any way on how I could do this?

Comment: If you select something then generally you have to group by that same thing. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: we solved this problem yesterday, didn't we? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011431/find-missing-date-and-add-them-into-result-mysql

Comment: @EstebanP. we did only for days and months. But I tried to do it for hours and weeks but it doesn't work

Comment: @Strawberry I couldn't quite get what you were trying to say, can you please repeat it?

Comment: You SELECT x, but you GROUP BY y. X and y have to be the same

Comment: Can you put an answer on how to do that since I am quite new to mysql and don't know it really well, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution for your problem would be to create a *calendar* table containing all the timestamps which you want to appear in your report.  If you can't create tables then you could use an inline approach e.g.

```
(
    SELECT '2017-11-07 00:00:00' AS ts UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-11-07 01:00:00'       UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2017-11-07 23:00:00'
) t
```

Then left join the calendar table to your current table and do a similar query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(t2.created),
    DATE_FORMAT(t1.ts, '%H - %d/%m/%y') AS datecreated
FROM calendar t1    -- possibly replace with inline table
LEFT JOIN mimesi_realtime.served_clips t2
    ON DATE_FORMAT(t1.ts, '%H - %d/%m/%y') = DATE_FORMAT(t2.created, '%H - %d/%m/%y')
WHERE t1.ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t1.ts, '%H - %d/%m/%y')
ORDER BY MIN(t1.ts)
```

If you don't want to work with a calendar table then another option would be to have a scheduled process which writes a single dummy record every hour.  This would guarantee that every point of time appears in your table.  It has the drawback of some wasted space and the time needed to set it up.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but the problem is that I can't modify the database but I can only run queries

Comment: @GPecchio Not a problem.  You can use an inline calendar table then, which your code would generate for the period of interest.

Comment: could the inline table be dynamic, since I need the data from the last 48 hours?

Comment: Yes, this is what I have in mind.  You could use dynamic SQL for that.  Just search SO and you will find such code.